# Passing parameter in command line, Assembly Programming

Tags: assembly, parameter-passing, nasm

Let me explain it briefly :).

I approach the argument 10, by using EBP register with ebx register because of the stack structure of which is containing EBP(base register), return address, # of parameter, parameter 1, parameter 2... since I don't use a local register. 
I could see the parameter was appropriately input as I could print it using call print_string. But, since < while: > code line, it seems like the string 10 doesn't seem to be read for the commend line does nothing when it comes to it.
I would gently ask where to start with the code.  thanks for reading.

Input : ./atoi 10
Result : 10

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

    segment .data

    segment .bss
    input   resw 1

    segment .text
    global  main
main:
    enter   0,0
    pusha
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    mov eax, [ebx+4]
     ; call print_string
    dump_stack 1,2,4
    mov ebx, 0      
    mov ecx, 10
while:
    cmp al, 0x0a
    je print
    sub eax, 0x30
    mov [input], eax
    mov eax, ebx
    mul ecx
    add eax, [input]
    mov ebx, eax
    jmp while
print:
    mov eax, ebx
    call print_int
    call print_nl

    popa
    mov     eax, 0 
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: `eax` is a pointer. You need to 1) dereference and 2) increment it. Also make sure you use the correct operand sizes (a char is 1 byte).

Comment: Replacing eax to %eax and resw to resb are the solution you mean?

Comment: `%eax` is at&t syntax and even there it doesn't dereference. I even missed `input`, that's defined as word which is doubly wrong. Yeah `resb` would be better but then of course you can't store 32 bits into it. Not that I understand why you need that at all.

Comment: Input is used for the space to sum integer numbers out of string which is created by subtraction like 'A'-'a'. ( you can think of atoi function. ).

Comment: Okay then use whatever is appropriate for the range of numbers you want to process. But make sure you use the proper size to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *while* loop doesn't read any characters! You retrieve these using `mov dl,[eax]`.
As you can see from the code below, there's no need to use a temporary *input* variable.

```
  xor   ebx, ebx            ;Result
while:
  movzx edx, byte ptr [eax] ;Read 1 character
  test  dl, dl              ;Test for end of string
  jz    print               ;End found
  sub   dl, 0x30            ;Go from character to value [0,9]
  imul  ebx, 10             ;Result x10
  add   ebx, edx            ;Add new digit
  inc   eax                 ;To next character
  jmp   while
```

Comment: xor   ebx, ebx            ;Result

Comment: sorry bro I don't get it, can you explain a little more? BTW These code don't work

Comment: `xor ebx,ebx` is meant to clear the `EBX` register. Just like `mov ebx,0` does but the instruction is better.

Comment: @jay: did you try single-stepping your code in a debugger?  That usually helps.

Comment: Late catch. Aren't these strings supposed to end with a terminating zero? Then instead of comparing with `0x0a` use `cmp dl,0`.